# git push fails with "Can't find entry point" in libssh and libcurl DLLs

Tags: git

I have a problem with git push. All other commands work good but not this one. When I run it in Git Bash literally nothing happens, when I use Atlassian SourceTree I get error messages.
I don't know how to properly translate this messages to English but I will try:

> Can't find entry point of EVP_aes128_ctr procedure in library C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\libssh2-1.dll

and:

> Can't find entry point of SSL_CTX_set_alpn_protos procedure in library C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\libcurl-4.dll

Of course I tried reinstalling both Git and SourceTree but it didn't help.

Git is integral part of my workflow and I don't know what to do :(

Comment: I also have this same problem, but not with these programs. The problem is that Windows its own uses libeay32.dll not the installed with Git or SourceTree. So, how do you open this programs? Maybe executing them from CMD and changing PATH env variable should fix the problem

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this kind of problem only occurs with the embedded version of git.

I had a slightly different message, but switching to system git fixed the issue for me.

See this link, similar problem with different message:
https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/32972886/git-remote-https.exe-libcurl-4.dll-the-procedure-entry-point-sslctxsetalpnprotos-could-not-be-located-in-the-dll